# Migrating Database from SQL Server to Azure using BACPAC file

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

I have a BACPAC file that I exported from SSMS with my schema as well as data, currently in my local disk.

The next step would be to upload the BACPAC file into a Blob Container and then import from my Azure SQL Server. Is there no way I can import the BACPAC file in my local disk directly to the Azure database without uploading it to a Blob container first?

If not, can someone explain what necessitates this intermediate step?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Data-Tier Application Wizard. Got to the **Object Explorer**, right-click **Databases** and choose **Import Data-tier Application**. On the *Import Settings* page, choose **Import from local disk**.

Comment: I need to migrate my database to Azure, not the other way round

Comment: You can migrate *into* Azure SQL Database in SSMS using the Data-Tier Application wizard if you connect against your Azure SQL Server. Did you have issues with this?

Comment: This does work since my current database is not too large, but I'm talking about a case where my database is fairly large; and using a .bacpac file is the better approach

Comment: Can you edit your original question to capture what situation you're actually asking about then? (This answer does address your question as written. )